# JSONpath to get a value by filter on another value

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have below JSON and i require to validate the status based on given id in my automation script. For that JSON path require

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 9905130204,
      "category": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string"
      },
      "name": "doggie",
      "photoUrls": [
        "string"
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string"
        }
      ],
      "status": "available"
    },
    {
      "id": 9905130203,
      "name": "Jeffs Doggie11/6/2019 2:44:53 PM",
      "photoUrls": [
        "string"
      ],
      "tags": [],
      "status": "available"
    },
    {
      "id": 9905130217,
      "name": "Goot Doggie",
      "photoUrls": [
        "https://media.karousell.com/media/photos/products/2017/09/14/doggi_door_stopper_1505372529_5cdd1eba0"
      ],
      "tags": [],
      "status": "available"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to extract `"status": "available"` based on `"id": 9905130217`. No clue how to do that, please help.

Comment: What tool are you reading this with? Can you use Python for instance?

Comment: Are you aware your json describes a 2d array? Is this deliberate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following jsonpath expression to find the status where id = n:

```
$.[?(@.id == 'n')].status
```

So, for your specific case:

```
$.[?(@.id == '9905130217')].status
```

Note, that this assumes id is unique.